# why I cannot set the value for the property in xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

only >>>>   `NSLog(@"%@", _currentPost[@"postString"]);`  print out the right string

`NSLog(@"%@",postTextView.text);` print out (null)  why?

How can i pass the value to textView.text?

Why I cannot pass the string to a textView, neither to a label?????

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface JCPostTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) PFObject *currentPost;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *postTextView;

@end
```

========================================================

```
#import "JCPostTableViewCell.h"

@implementation JCPostTableViewCell

@synthesize postTextView;

-(void) layoutSubviews
{
    postTextView.text = _currentPost[@"postString"];
    NSLog(@"%@", _currentPost[@"postString"]);
    NSLog(@"%@", postTextView.text);
}
```

Comment: That's not the way you use `NSLog`. It will show a warning, don't ignore warnings. Use `NSLog` with a format string to prevent memory errors.

Comment: My guess is the outlet is not connected and is `nil`. Please verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the outlet is not connected in IB and you are therefore effectively calling:

```
NSLog(nil);
```

Which will produce no output.  you are supposed to use constant strings as the format string to `NSLog` and if you do you will see `(null)` output at least:

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.postViewText.text);
```

Add the following code at the start of the method to verify if the outlet is connected:

```
NSAssert(self.postViewText, @"postViewText outlet not connected!");
```

Comment: you are right, how could I connect the outlet in IB?

Comment: Thank you for you answer.  the NSLog() is just to test, my point is how can i pass the "postString" to the textView.text?

Comment: Your code will do that once the outlet is connected.

Comment: the outlet is connected. :(

Answer (score 0):

you can not connect the outlet connection.[image]

same as the you connect the textview and set the delegate method after that check

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.postViewText.text);
```